# Why is an extra line of code needed in a While(true) loop?

Tags: java, event-dispatch-thread

I am writing a game for a CS class.

There is a GUI `MyDisplay` which is an extended `KeyListener` with a `JFrame` with a packed `JPanel[][]` for an instance variable.

`MyGame` has a private `enum` called `GameState` which is either `MENU`, `PLAY`, `QUIT`, or `PAUSE`.  `MyGame` has the `static void main` method which has the following construct:

`MyGame` is as follows:

```
public class MyGame
{
    /* Private instance fields and constructor left out.  
    Constructor initializes a MyDisplay and state = MENU */

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MyGame g = new MyGame();
        while(true)
        {
            gstate = g.getState();
            if(gstate == GameState.PLAY)
                g.play();
            else if(gstate == GameState.PAUSE)
                g.pause();
            else if(gstate == GameState.MENU)
                g.menu();
        }
    }

    /* implementation of MyGame methods */
}
```

Where `play`, `pause`, and `menu` invoke various calls to `MyDisplay` to draw new stuff.  The only way the state can change is if the user presses enter.  Then, `MyDisplay` calls a `MyGame` method called `enterPressed` which changes the state accordingly.

When I compile this, the game does not behave normally.  When I press enter (and print out the state to check), I notice, as it should, that MENU changes to PLAY.  But even though the state is in PLAY, `g.play()` is not being evaluated (I tested whether or not the console printed out a test phrase in an added line of code in `play()`).

But what really confuses me is that when I enter any call to `System.out`, such as `System.out.print("");` in the `while` loop of `main`, everything works fine, and `g.play()` gets called as it should.

Comment: never make a loop without sleep : you don't let the other threads do their work.

Comment: @dystroy `g.play()` contains sleep - should I post `g.play()`?

Comment: I would check that the state is different to the one you have already performed. This means that instead of constant updated, you only update when the state changes.

Comment: @PeterLawrey `g.play()` has to be constantly updated.

Comment: @VF1 Instead of calling it constantly and recalculating everything, you could call it only when something changes. i.e. make it event driven.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are hitting a [thread starvation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/starvelive.html) case. Because your initial state is `MENU` the loop consumes all the cpu, and the UI doesn't have the chance to consume your key press event. 
Try with a small sleep in your while, like: `sleep(10)`

[Here](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=24220.0) you will find more informations and a lot of alternatives, even a `Timer` is much more CPU friendly, but there are better ways, depends on your game logic.

Comment: Thanks.  That worked.  My `sleep` was only in `play` because when I was first making the game, I was only running `while(true) g.play()`, so it was taken care of.  Extending the functionality to having multiple states was the problem, since the other methods don't sleep.  But why did `System.out.print("")` work?

Comment: @VF1 You're welcome. Because when performing an IO operation, the UI thread was able to gain CPU time.

Comment: pardon the repetitive comment, I just worry that since I edited it you may not have seen my recently added question - do you know why `System.out.print("")` let the event thread use the CPU?

Comment: @VF1 I edited my comment too :), after noticing. `System.out.print("")` is a IO operation and while performed it will allow other threads to gain CPU time, in your case the UI thread to consume the key event.

Comment: Typically when a system does an I/O operation, that allows other threads in the application to get a chance at CPU time.  It's basically because you are asking the OS to go do some I/O, and that usually takes much longer than processing and doesn't involve the current thread.

Comment: @dan @rcook But leaving it as `System.out.print("")` is inelegant, right?

Comment: @VF1 Right :), even the sleep method is inelegant, but many are suggesting this use, see: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/21157/Structure_of_simple_game_1146872_11.jsp (first link on a google search:), not endorsing bb). Ideally you should `wait` on the user input.